# Regex in python that matches a word containing 'z', not at the start or end of the word

Tags: python, regex

Consider a sentence which will have some words which may or may not start or end with 'z'.

This was my code :

```
reg_9 = re.compile(r'\b[^z]\w+z\w+[^z]\b')
sentence = "this sentence contains zatstart azb pole ab noaz yeszishere z_is_op"
reg_9.findall(sentence)
```

So according to above regex all strings within boundary '\b', which does not start with 'z' and does not ends with 'z' (that [^z] at start and end) but having 'z' somewhere in between which is given by '\w+z\w+' in my regex.

In the output I am getting this :

```
[' azb ', ' yeszishere ']
```

So can someone tell why this output strings consists of those extra spaces at start and end ?

Comment: The `\b[^z]` part of your regex also matches space characters after a word boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `\w+` optional, i.e. use `\w*` instead.  But, I would phrase your regex as:

```py
reg_9 = re.compile(r'\b[^\WzZ]\w*z\w*[^\WzZ]\b')
sentence = "this sentence contains zatstart azb pole ab noaz yeszishere z_is_op"
print(reg_9.findall(sentence))  # ['azb', 'yeszishere']
```

This regex pattern says to:

```
\b       match a word boundary
[^\WzZ]  match any word character OTHER than z or Z
\w*      zero or more word characters
z        z
\w*      zero or more word characters
[^\WzZ]  match any word character OTHER than z or Z
\b       match a word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for this task can look like

```
\b(?!DOES_NOT_START_WITH)(?=\w*?MUST_CONTAIN)\w+\b(?<!DOES_NOT_END_WITH)
```

You can use

```py
import re
reg_9 = re.compile(r'\b(?!z)(?=\w*?z)\w+\b(?<!z)')
sentence = "this sentence contains zatstart azb pole ab noaz yeszishere z_is_op"
print(reg_9.findall(sentence))
# => ['azb', 'yeszishere']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jpNOXn/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cYQQA5).

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!z)` - immediately on the right, there should be no `z`
- `(?=\w*?z)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `z` after any zero or more word chars
- `\w+` - `one or more word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!z)` - a negative lookbehind, immediately on the left, there should be no `z`.